# Updating Random Integers (swift, spritekit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a random integer that needs to update every second, but my issue is that the random int cannot be defined outside of a function because it is an random int with the range of 0 to the screen size

```
      var randomX = UInt32(self.size.width)
```

I cannot use self.size.width outside of a function. At first I thought maybe its not updating because its 1. Declared in the function didMoveToView() and 2. I declared it using "let" instead of "var". If I declare it in my function that updates every second, the variable cannot be used outside of that function which is a huge problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your `var` as an instance variable of your class (outside a method), update it in a method, and use it anywhere else in an instance of that class.

```
class RTest {
    var randomX: UInt32
    init() {
        self.randomX = 2;
    }

    func rx5()->UInt32 {
        return self.randomX * 5
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work, cant do that because I need the random int to be between 0 and the size of the screen of any device. And I cant use self.size.width outside of a method

Comment: There's no need to use self.size.width outside of a method.  Update the instance variable inside a method but define it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global class variable so you could access it anywhere in the class

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {
var screenWidth: CGFloat = 0.0; //Global variable for this class

   func getRand() -> UInt32 {
       //generate your random number
       return UInt32(self.screenWidth)
   }

   func useRandom() {
       //call getRand anytime you want to generatea a new random num
       var myRandNum = getRand()
   }

   func override viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       self.screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
   }
}
```

Code not tested but should give you an idea on how to go about it.
hope that helps.